# Python smtplib send email to recipient in correspondant row

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Is there a way to send a mail with python smtplib whose recipient varies by row in a dataframe? (one to one mail)
I can send a different message by row, but I cant replicate the same with the receiver, since I can only send them either to one, or to all of the receivers that I mention. I cant send it to the receiver in the correspondant row. I have the following code:

```
for each_line in df.index:
    z = message (its an example... this part is like df['first column'] + " hello " + df['second column'])
    MY_ADDRESS = "mymail@mail.com" 
    MY_PASSWORD = "mypassword"   
    RECIPIENT_ADDRESS = PROBLEM HERE (I can only write one to multiple email receivers, but not to iterate by row as the message).
    HOST_ADDRESS = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com' 
    HOST_PORT = 587  
    # Connection with the server
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host=HOST_ADDRESS, port=HOST_PORT)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(MY_ADDRESS, MY_PASSWORD)
    # Creation of the MIMEMultipart Object
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    # Setup of MIMEMultipart Object Header
    message['From'] = MY_ADDRESS
    message['To'] = RECIPIENT_ADDRESS
    message['Subject'] = "Alerts"

    # Creation of a MIMEText Part
    textPart = MIMEText(z)

    # Part attachment
    message.attach(textPart)

    # Send Email and close connection
    server.send_message(message)
    server.quit()
```

Is there a way to do this?
My dataframe has a row which includes the respective receiver email address, but I cant use it. I get the following error:
" AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Thanks in advance :)

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I solved this adding the following code:

```
#This goes inside the previous for loop
for each_line in DataFrame.index:
    X = DataFrame['Column'][each_line]
    RECIPIENT_ADDRESS = X
    print(X)

#Then (inside the for loop)
    message['To'] = RECIPIENT_ADDRESS
```

Hope this work for you too :)